# VB.net suggestions to avoid keyloggers spy on my textbox password?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, keylogger

How it could be done?

So far i seen on Google:

- Virtual keyboard
- Add some events to my textbox to cancel the key event.
- When key pressed record what has been pressed save and then simulate other 10 random keys?

what else can be done and not to build the whole anti-keylogger antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done anything that your imagination let you:

- You could tell the user to put his/her password using the key in the direction you want, for example on the right. And control the symbols with your application (with a `Dictionary` for example). You could show a standart keyboard picture to the user to be sure.
- You could tell the user to put a letter you show to him/her every X keys pressed, or just press any key he/she wants and discard it.
- You could tell the user to put a letter you show to him/her after each key of password pressed.
- You could tell the user to put only the even characters of his password, and later ask for the rest.
- You could tell the user to put the password backwards.

But I think a Virtual Keyboard is the best option.